# command poetry install produces error with lxml

Tags: python, lxml, python-poetry

I cloned a repository containing python code managed via poetry.

inside the project i ran the command `poetry install` to install the dependencies.

it installed all the dependencies that were contained except `lxml`, printing the following error

```
Installing lxml (4.9.1): Failed

  ChefBuildError

  Backend subprocess exited when trying to invoke build_wheel

  Building lxml version 4.9.1.
  Building without Cython.
  Building against pre-built libxml2 andl libxslt libraries
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml
  copying src\lxml\builder.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml
  copying src\lxml\cssselect.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml
  copying src\lxml\doctestcompare.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml
  copying src\lxml\ElementInclude.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml
  copying src\lxml\pyclasslookup.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml
  copying src\lxml\sax.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml
  copying src\lxml\usedoctest.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml
  copying src\lxml\_elementpath.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml
  copying src\lxml\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\includes
  copying src\lxml\includes\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\includes
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\html
  copying src\lxml\html\builder.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\html
  copying src\lxml\html\clean.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\html
  copying src\lxml\html\defs.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\html
  copying src\lxml\html\diff.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\html
  copying src\lxml\html\ElementSoup.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\html
  copying src\lxml\html\formfill.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\html
  copying src\lxml\html\html5parser.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\html
  copying src\lxml\html\soupparser.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\html
  copying src\lxml\html\usedoctest.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\html
  copying src\lxml\html\_diffcommand.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\html
  copying src\lxml\html\_html5builder.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\html
  copying src\lxml\html\_setmixin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\html
  copying src\lxml\html\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\html
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\isoschematron
  copying src\lxml\isoschematron\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\isoschematron
  copying src\lxml\etree.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml
  copying src\lxml\etree_api.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml
  copying src\lxml\lxml.etree.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml
  copying src\lxml\lxml.etree_api.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml
  copying src\lxml\includes\c14n.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\includes
  copying src\lxml\includes\config.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\includes
  copying src\lxml\includes\dtdvalid.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\includes
  copying src\lxml\includes\etreepublic.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\includes
  copying src\lxml\includes\htmlparser.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\includes
  copying src\lxml\includes\relaxng.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\includes
  copying src\lxml\includes\schematron.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\includes
  copying src\lxml\includes\tree.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\includes
  copying src\lxml\includes\uri.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\includes
  copying src\lxml\includes\xinclude.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\includes
  copying src\lxml\includes\xmlerror.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\includes
  copying src\lxml\includes\xmlparser.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\includes
  copying src\lxml\includes\xmlschema.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\includes
  copying src\lxml\includes\xpath.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\includes
  copying src\lxml\includes\xslt.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\includes
  copying src\lxml\includes\__init__.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\includes
  copying src\lxml\includes\etree_defs.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\includes
  copying src\lxml\includes\lxml-version.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\includes
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\isoschematron\resources
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\isoschematron\resources\rng
  copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\rng\iso-schematron.rng -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\isoschematron\resources\rng
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl
  copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\RNG2Schtrn.xsl -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl
  copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\XSD2Schtrn.xsl -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1
  copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1\iso_abstract_expand.xsl -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1
  copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1\iso_dsdl_include.xsl -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1
  copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1\iso_schematron_message.xsl -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1
  copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1\iso_schematron_skeleton_for_xslt1.xsl -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1
  copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1\iso_svrl_for_xslt1.xsl -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1
  copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1\readme.txt -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1
  running build_ext
  building 'lxml.etree' extension
  error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/


  at ~\AppData\Roaming\pypoetry\venv\Lib\site-packages\poetry\installation\chef.py:152 in _prepare
      148│
      149│                 error = ChefBuildError("\n\n".join(message_parts))
      150│
      151│             if error is not None:
    → 152│                 raise error from None
      153│
      154│             return path
      155│
      156│     def _prepare_sdist(self, archive: Path, destination: Path | None = None) -> Path:

Note: This error originates from the build backend, and is likely not a problem with poetry but with lxml (4.9.1) not supporting PEP 517 builds. You can verify this by running 'pip wheel --use-pep517 "lxml (==4.9.1) ; python_version >= "2.7" and python_full_version < "3.0.0" or python_full_version >= "3.5.0""'.
```

i have `python 3.11.2` and `poetry 1.4.0` and i'm using windows 10.

i tried installing `lxml` with pip.
I tried downloading the binaries of `libxml2` and `libxslt` (also adding them to the PATH). I take the binaries here https://www.zlatkovic.com/libxml.en.html

none of these things brought results

Answer (score 0):

Based on your error message you should try to install `Microsoft C++ Build Tools`, you can use this link https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/

Then you can try installing `lxml` again

Comment: ok, now the error has changed. I have: `Could not find function xmlCheckVersion in library libxml2. Is libxml2 installed?`. I used this [link](https://pages.lip6.fr/Jean-Francois.Perrot/XML-Int/Session1/WinLibxml.html) to take libxml2 and libxslt. but it doesn't work anyway. I guess the problem is the libraries (I read that since they are not python modules they must be installed alternatively)

Comment: you can go to http://www.xmlsoft.org/downloads.html.

Comment: really sorry for the inconvenience (I'm still learning). while installing I had a problem with the command `cmake --build libxml2-v2.10.3-build` which produces the following error `MSBuild version 17.5.0+6f08c67f3 for .NET Framework
MSBUILD : error MSB1009: Project file does not exist.
Switch: ALL_BUILD.vcxproj`. probably resulting from: Could NOT find Iconv (missing: Iconv_LIBRARY) (found version "1.14") result of comand: `cmake -S libxml2-v2.10.3 -B libxml2-v2.10.3-build`

Comment: Download Iconv library for Windows, the 32 or 64 bits version, extract the content then add the bin to your system path, https://sourceforge.net/projects/gnuwin32/files/libiconv/1.14/

Comment: Maybe you should start from scratch and see if you can find a tutorial on google or chatGPT to help you